# How do I use gulp to convert all jsx files to JavaScript?

Tags: gulp, browserify, reactjs

How do I use gulp to convert all jsx files to JavaScript?

When I try to do so, I get the error *undefined function require*

I'm using the following script.

What I want to do is use gulp to convert all *jsx to JavaScript*. Also use *browserfy* in my jsx files.

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var react = require('gulp-react')

gulp.task('transpile-js', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/*.jsx')
    .pipe(react({harmony: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
})
```

I have jsx files in the src directory. I want to convert them into one JavaScript file and store the result in the build directory

Comment: hey, have you succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my [domno repo](https://github.com/coma/domno) for more:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    uglify       = require('gulp-uglify'),
    browserify   = require('browserify'),
    source       = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    buffer       = require('vinyl-buffer');

gulp.task('script', function () {

    return browserify({
            entries  : ['the/path/to/the/main/entry/file.js'],
            transform: ['babelify']
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dir.web));
});
```

There are several ways of [configuring Browserify](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook)...